# javascript array into key value space separated string

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, reduce

I have an array like this `["Asthma", "Allergy", "Sports and Fitness"]` and I need to convert that array to a string of key value pair - something like below:

```
prop1: Asthma prop1: Allergy prop1: Sports and Fitness prop2: Asthma, prop2: Allergy prop2: Sports and Fitness
```

Is this possible to do this using `Array.Proptotype.Reduce()`?

```
var propertyObjectRefinable = "";
jQuery("p[data-action='related-articles']>a span.media-content")
  .map(function() {
    return jQuery.trim($(this).text());
  }).get().forEach(function(item){
    propertyObjectRefinable += "RefinableString15:" + item + " " + "RefinableString16:" + item + " ";     
});
```

gives me something like this, which I don't like because it is not in order

```
RefinableString15:Sports and Fitness RefinableString16:Sports and Fitness RefinableString15:Allergy RefinableString16:Allergy RefinableString15:Asthma RefinableString16:Asthma "
```

Comment: Is there any relevant reason to use .reduce?

Comment: Not really. I was just thinking from accumulation perspective

Comment: Well. Using `map` and `reduce` you can come up with something like this, as a starter point: http://jsfiddle.net/briosheje/3r805z6g/3/ . Just take it as an example (though it's really close to an ideal solution), I came up with this in my coffee break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do it like this with help of [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)**

```js
let arr =["Asthma", "Allergy", "Sports and Fitness"];
let op = arr.map(e=>`prop1: ${e}`).join(' ');
console.log(op);
```

**In case you want more than one property**

```js
let arr =["Asthma", "Allergy", "Sports and Fitness"];
let op = arr.reduce((e,a)=>{
 e[0].push(`prop1: ${a}`);
 e[1].push(`prop2: ${a}`);
 return e;
 },[[],[]]);
 let final = op.map(e=> e.join(' ')).join(' ');
console.log(final);
```

Comment: Just a side note: he needs two properties (prop1, prop2). Check the updated question.

Comment: @briosheje thanks for informing about update :) updated my answer too :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use map:

```
["Asthma", "Allergy", "Sports and Fitness"].map((item) => {
    return `prop1: ${item}`;
}).toString();
```

or more humanly readable & cleaner:

```
let arr = ["Asthma", "Allergy", "Sports and Fitness"];
let newArr = arr.map((item) => {
    return `prop1: ${item}`;
});
console.log(newArr.toString());
```

Output:

```
"prop1: Asthma,prop1: Allergy,prop1: Sports and Fitness"
```

Map will return you a new array containing the new items.

Comment: I want a string, and I have two properties prop1 and prop2 that need to be in order

Comment: I updated the answer - using toString will give you your final string. You could also use `.join('')`